# Why forcing Garbage Collection increases the memory allocated to java process?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

So I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Creating array...");
    Integer[] integers = new Integer[Integer.MAX_VALUE/32];
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Destroying array");
    integers = null;
    //System.gc ();
    //System.runFinalization ();
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

When I run this code I after about 5 seconds I will see 268 MB of ram is allocated to java process in Activity Monitor.

When I **uncomment** the commented lines (System.gc and the following line) after I see "Destroying array" in console, the memory allocated increases to 278 MB.

I can understand that the memory is not freed up because System.gc() is only a hint to the JVM, but why the 10MB increase? What has been loaded at this point to the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocated memory does not necessarily mean memory occupied by objects. It can be empty heap space.

Java GCs are copying/compacting collectors, for copying to work they need some TO-space as copy destination for the non-garbage.

And by forcing a garbage collection you are interfering with the GC's heuristics, e.g. with its pause time goals or its throughput goals. To compensate it may decide to give itself more breathing room - within the bounds of the configured maximum heap size - to still meet those goals.

I don't know if it applies to all GC algorithms, but logging with `-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy` might provide some insight.

Comment: It doesn't force garbage collection, though.

Comment: I didn't claim it does.

Comment: "...and by forcing a garbage collection"? I guess we have different definitions of "force".

Comment: JVM implementations are not required to honor it. E.g. `System.gc()` can be disabled with a command line flag. But generally speaking, under those configurations (i.e. the default config for hotspot) where `System.gc()` is not a noop it forces a GC at a point in time where it wouldn't happen otherwise. One thing is what the implementation is allowed to do, the other how the implementation actually behaves under normal circumstances.

Comment: So the use of the word "force" is erroneous, because the JLS specifically states you cannot force a GC. My point is that the OP correctly states it's a hint, which you acknowledge, then you answer as though it's being forced. Even when an implementation *does* fire a GC ithe still occurs at an essentially arbitrary time. I'm uncomfortable with using language outside the spec because it's misleading, especially since there are multiple implementations in the wild in general use.

Comment: The spec says its a hint. But the action - call to System.gc() - always resulting in an reaction (an unscheduled GC) is a valid implementation. So in actual implementations it can and does amount to forcing (cf. Newton) a GC. What you're doing is describing a mechanical system based on schematics from which it was built. I'm looking at the actual system here. Just a different point of view. Anyway, it's not essential to my answer, just arguing semantics.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking an invalid question.

**You cannot force GC and also any memory consumption is completely an implementation detail**. JVM can do a lot of stuff, so the question is completely invalid to ask.

On different machines and JVMs it could behave differently.

Comment: It's not invalid to ask, and it *is* answerable, although said answer will depend on the jvm, os, architecture, etc.

Comment: This is funny, but I don't want to play with words.