# Java: Memory Heap increases with each Gargbage Collector´s cycle

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, garbage-collection, profiler

i have a problem with my JavaFX Desktop Application, i was running the NetBeans´s profiler in order to see the app´s performance and i discovered that when the gc do its cycle, the memory heap increases a lot, is about 3gbs currently and gettin bigger, i dont know why this happens.

The weird thing is that memory heap increases but it is never used to the level it increases, the other thing is that as soon as the gc ends its cycle, the memory used starts to increase to a top level and dicreases again with the gc cycle and go on.

I already tried to optimize my code but it doesn´t work!

Any idea?

Thanks.

Here an image of Netbeans´s profiler graphs --
[image: NetBeans Profiling]

Comment: Java programs may run code in the background that generates garbage. Even if that wouldn't normally happen, the *monitoring* of the JVM you're doing requires the JVM to send data to the profiler, hence generating garbage, so it is perfectly normal for a continual generation of garbage. *"the memory used starts to increase"* is normal and expected, and *"dicreases again with the gc cycle"* is expected too, since that is what GC is supposed to do, right?

Comment: Check accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380208/why-forcing-garbage-collection-increases-the-memory-allocated-to-java-process

Comment: So, in this case the profiler is modifying the global behaviour of the jvm, and it´s what i am seeing, not just my app´s behav?, and in relation with: "is what GC is supposed to do", i dont know :s , i supposed that if i wasn´t having any interaction with the app and the app was not doing any work, the used heap will maintain in a stable line, but it did not :s .

Comment: Perhaps there is a mismatch in the monitoring tool’s polling interval and the actual gc cycles. Normally, we assume that the tool receives notifications about the actual gc events, but this doesn’t have to be the case.

Comment: @Andreas This doesn't make sense. Sending data to the profiler should not be visible on a graph showing 3 GB memory usage. That the heap grows between GCs is obvious, but why do nearly 3 GB allocated, when it seems to work rather well with 1.2 GB? Maybe no `-Xmx` switch was given and the JVM simply takes a lot in order to reduce the GC overhead?